# Installing mongoDB and getting a path error

Tags: mongodb, command-line, cmd, git-bash

I'm trying to install a MEAN stack in a windows machine and I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbxVuaw_ktw But I get an error. I confirmed the path is correct but I still get this error

This is the code I am using according to my paths and the error

> $ ./mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath "C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/data/db" --logpath "C:/Program Files
>   /MongoDB/Server/3.2/data/log/mongodb.log" --logappend
>
> 2016-11-15T14:08:29.071-0500 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global
>   initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "C:/Program
>   Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/data/log/mongodb.log"

It looks like it's escaping the space in Program Files instead of treating it as one single Path location. Is that what's happening? How do I get passed this point?

Thanks

Comment: Put all the paths in quotes like this - "C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/data/db"

Comment: For your information, putting things like data and logs under *C:\Program Files* isn't good practice - that's supposed to be for the application's executable files. Try using C:\ProgramData, or a location under your user's workspace.

Comment: as Abhay said the value of dbpath should be enclosed in double quotes as well as the value for logpath.

Comment: @AbhayPS I saw that in another tutorial and tried it and it still didn't accept  it. I guess I forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: Can you try it again with the values quoted, and update your question with these details if you're still getting the same problem?

Comment: I edited my question. And I tried with and without quotes

Comment: I got it to work. It doesn't work through Git Bash. You have to use the Command Prompt with Administrative authorization and change the code a little, no quotes either. I'll post the solution, although I hate to answer my own questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving this error, most likely you've been using GitBash. Instead, use Command Prompt (Admin) and use the code as shown below

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/data/db --logpath C:/Program Files /MongoDB/Server/3.2/data/log/mongodb.log --logappend
```

As suggested by Vince Bowdren (see comments on the question). Do not use Program Files. It is much better to use the user's workplace or project's root. However for the sake of learning MongoDB any place is as good as any.